# Why Wildfly 8.1.0 final return java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: when deploying ejb module with a remote application library but glassfish doesn’t?

Tags: java, netbeans, jboss, ejb-3.1, wildfly-8

I tried to create a simple EJB remote client sample but I keep getting `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:` any time I tried to deploy the EJB.

The Remote Java Library File Structure is:

> ```
> > TestRemoteInterface     
>     --Source Package      
>        -- bean
>           --TestBeanRemote.java   
>     -- Libraries      
>        -- Java EE 6 API Library       
>        --JDK 1.8
> ```

The EJB Module File Structure is:

> ```
> > TestEJBModule   
>     --Source Package      
>        -- bean
>           --TestBean.java     
>     -- Libraries  
>        -- TestRemoteInterface – dist/TestRemoteInterface    
>        -- Java EE 6 API Library       
>        -- JDK 1.8
> ```

TestBeanRemote.java

```
package bean;
import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TestBeanRemote {

    String getName(String name);

}
```

TestBean .java

> package bean;
>
> import javax.ejb.Stateless;
>
> @Stateless public class TestBean implements TestBeanRemote {
>
> ```
> @Override
> public String getName(String name) {
>     return "Here is my " + name;
> }    }
> ```

Question: When I try to deploy the TestEJBModule on get the follow log:

> WARN  [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-6) Failed to define
>   class bean.TestBean in Module "deployment.TestEJBModule.jar:main" from
>   Service Module Loader: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link
>   bean/TestBean (Module "deployment.TestEJBModule.jar:main" from Service
>   Module Loader)

....

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bean/TestBeanRemote
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_05]
```

....

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bean.TestBeanRemote from
>   [Module "deployment.TestEJBModule.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]

...

> Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: Failed to link bean/TestBean
>   (Module "deployment.TestEJBModule.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader)   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.defineClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:487)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]
>   .....
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: bean/TestBeanRemote

.....

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: bean.TestBeanRemote from
>   [Module "deployment.TestEJBModule.jar:main" from Service Module
>   Loader]   at
>   org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
>   [jboss-modules.jar:1.3.3.Final]

When I tried to deploy this same sample with Glassfish 4. It works fine.

**NB: I am using netbeans 8.0.1**

There appear to be a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690027/wildfly-8-host-ejb-3-x-application-problems) but it didn't help much. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you deploying `TestRemoteInterface` and `TestEJBModule` as two separated jars? If so, both jars are in separated classloaders and this is why you get NoClassDefFoundError. Have you considered to deploy an ear file containing both jars?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deploying the TestRemoteInterface jar to the sever first. Then I added it to the project manifest.mf as a dependency.

example:

```
Dependencies: deployment.TestRemoteInterface.jar
```

Another option if you are using maven is the use maven dependencies manifest

```
<configuration>
   <archive>
      <manifestEntries>
         <Dependencies>TestRemoteInterface.jar</Dependencies>
      </manifestEntries>
   </archive>
</configuration>
```